# PHP + MYSQL Seating Reservation System. Counting free seats

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, html-table

Basically I have a query that finds the number of free seats within this school Hall (ones that aren't booked).

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS freeseats FROM schoolHall WHERE status=0");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
?>
```

On my home page i currently have a table containing buttons that direct you to other pages:

```
<table id='table-2'>
<tr>
<th>Home Page</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="School Hall" ONCLICK="window.location.href='schoolHall.php'"></td>
<td> 
.......
```

I would like to have the number of free seats found in the query next to this button in a separate cell. How do I do this?

Comment: what have you actually tried?

Comment: You should research AJAX (and, probably, JQuery because it makes life better). Basically, you want your button to call your script *without* reloading the page, and write the answer in an empty table cell, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps;

```
<table id='table-2'>
<tr>
<th>Home Page</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="School Hall" ONCLICK="window.location.href='schoolHall.php'"></td>
<td><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>
<td>
```

Comment: You have to include your query in the top of the page.Check $row[0] really returns any value.

Comment: Does the query return the correct info?  If you post more details I'll try to help